# HTTP connection working on Elastic Load Balancer (Classic Load Balancer) but not on HTTPS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, https, amazon-elb

[image]I am trying to set up an Elastic Load Balancer to be in front of my EC2 instance and redirect the traffic to it. My web app on EC2 is running HTTPS on port 3000. My ELB works nice when I start the web app over HTTP on port 3000 and I set up the ELB's port 80 to redirect HTTP traffic to HTTP 3000 of my instance. But when I start my app over HTTPS on port 3000 and then change the ELB's listeners, so it redirects HTTPS requests to port 80 to HTTPS 3000 of my instance, then the webpage does not work.

I have already created the SSL certificates, they are validated, uploaded to AWS Certificates Manager and my ELB is already taking them when serving HTTPS. My web app also has the certificate, so it's taking it to create the HTTPS environment on its side.

Also, my security group has connections on port 443 over HTTPS allowed.

Any suggestions, please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: " the webpage does not work." - is not specific. What exactly is happening? Any screenshots, error messages? Why do you use non-standard port for https? Also if you use port 3000, why do you open port 443 in security groups?

Comment: Classic load balancer does not have redirections capability, so its not clear what do you mean by writing " it redirects HTTPS requests to port 80 to HTTPS 3000"?

Comment: Hi @Marcin, just added a screenshot of my listeners. My LB is a classic one. The webpage just says "This page isn't working. (IP Address) didn't send any data" when accessing it at the moment with those listeners. I thought HTTPS could only be served with classic load balancers?

Comment: CLB is old type. Normally ALB would be use these days. Also why you keep using all these strange ports? Https is 443, not 80 or 81. Its very confusing what you are trying to achieve and what is your setup.

Comment: What I have understood so far is: 1) only ports above 1024 can be used on EC2 instance. So my app is running on port 3000. 2) Consequently, I have to redirect all users logging in the website of my web app to this port 3000 of the instance. 3) The way of achieving this is via a LB. 4) As users directly consume port 80 of any IP address when typing on the browser's navigation bar, any redirection that I make has to go from port 80 of LB to port 3000 of my instance. Is all of this correct?

Comment: You should have secure listener on load balancer at port 443 (https). Deploy SSL cert for your own domain that you bought on the listener. Instance port is  3000 but protocol is http (not https). For testing use your own domain, not IP nor EB default domain.

Comment: So far, I used this configuration with an Application Load Balancer for HTTP requests and it worked. Switching to HTTPS did not work

Comment: I'm confused now. You wrote that you use CLB, but now you have ALB? Please make your question very specific and clearify exactly what is your setup.

Comment: I have tested both ALB and CLB. I don't have any preference at all, I just need that the web app is reached. As you recommend ALB, I'm switching to it

Comment: Did you follow [aws docs](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-https-configuration/) for https on eb?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235035/discussion-between-martinhn-and-marcin).

Comment: Sorry, I can't chat at the moment.

Comment: OK, let me follow your docs first. Thank you!